# Take numbers from a list in a specific order in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I would like to remove the numbers from the list of three in three positions and then store them in a new list. I thought of doing something like n+3 but don´t know how to implement it.

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 1, 6, 1, 4, 7, 2, 4, 8, 4, 6, 9, 6, 5]
```

This is my list and I would like to create a new list like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `new_list = list(set(original_list))`

Comment: It really isn't clear what your criteria is here. Please provide an adequate specification so that an answer can be provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to pick one element in every three elements. For that, you can use slicing `[::3]`, where `3` means the step size:

```py
lst = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 1, 6, 1, 4, 7, 2, 4, 8, 4, 6, 9, 6, 5]

output = lst[::3]
print(output) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using set removes all multiples and also changes the type so then we convert it back to a list. Learn more about set here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets

```py
my_list=[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 1, 6, 1, 4, 7, 2, 4, 8, 4, 6, 9, 6, 5]

new_list=list(set(my_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that your question needs improvement, however, if i understood correctly, you want to remove redundancy in which case a much much simpler solution is to convert your list to a set and it'll be taken care of like so:

```
unique = set(some_list)
```

Do note that unique's api will be that of a set but if you specifically need a list you can do this:

```
unique = list(set(some_list))
```

Happy coding-

Comment: It's not clear this is what they are really trying to do. The unique numbers seem to be an artifact of the question—they were clear that the position was the determinant for inclusion. Even if it is, it seems like this solution will not guarantee the order of the elements as the OP's desired result does.